How do I skip the next jobs in GitLab CI if the first job was not added to the pipeline?
I am trying to create a CI for Terraform code.
The first job is a linter, which should run only if Terraform files have been changed.
test_lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - |
        cd xxx
        terraform init
        terraform fmt -check -recursive -diff
        terraform validate
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      changes:
        compare_to: 'refs/heads/main'
        paths:
          - 'projects/xxx/*'
          - 'xxx/*'
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      when: never

If the files have not been changed, I do not need to run the second job with terraform plan and the third job with terraform apply.
test_plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - |
        cd xxx
        terraform init
        terraform plan -out=$PLAN -parallelism=30
        terraform show --json $PLAN | convert_report > $PLAN_JSON
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - xxx/$PLAN
    reports:
      terraform: xxx/$PLAN_JSON
  resource_group: terraform-state


test_apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - |
        cd xxx
        terraform apply $PLAN
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"' ### Apply only after merging
  resource_group: terraform-state

How can I skip the plan and apply jobs if the first job was not added to the pipeline? My MR settings does not allow merging if no pipelines have passed, so I need an additional dummy job that starts only when these three jobs are skipped, or not added to pipeline at all? after MR i don't need to run dummy job
I tried to use rules like in plan job for example
rules:
  - if: '$CI_JOB_STATUS == "success" && $CI_JOB_STAGE == "lint"' # here i mean previous job
  when: never

but it's not works
Maybe i just need to take names of previous job and add it to rule in next job with "when: never"
Like a
rules:
 - if: $PREVIOUS JOB (or STAGE) = not created
   when: never


You already have a working rule for lint. Can't you just use the same rule for plan and apply?

I thought there have any more beauty methods to do this without repeating code in each job.
And another problem - how to run (if first three job skip) and don't run (if first three stages will apply) dummy succeed job just to allow to merge (yes, it looks like another question ((

Based on your comment and your request to a solution that does not duplicate code I would suggest you use a template for the needed rule:
.only_on_changes: &only_on_changes
  if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
  changes:
    compare_to: 'refs/heads/main'
    paths:
      - 'projects/xxx/*'
      - 'xxx/*'

test_lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - |
        cd xxx
        terraform init
        terraform fmt -check -recursive -diff
        terraform validate
  rules:
    - *only_on_changes
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      when: never

test_plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - |
        cd xxx
        terraform init
        terraform plan -out=$PLAN -parallelism=30
        terraform show --json $PLAN | convert_report > $PLAN_JSON
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - xxx/$PLAN
    reports:
      terraform: xxx/$PLAN_JSON
  rules:
    - *only_on_changes
  resource_group: terraform-state


test_apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - |
        cd xxx
        terraform apply $PLAN
  rules:
    - *only_on_changes
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"' ### Apply only after merging
  resource_group: terraform-state

If you want another job that only runs whenever the previous rule does not apply you could negate it and add it to your dummy job:
.only_on_no_changes: &only_on_no_changes
  if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
  changes:
    compare_to: 'refs/heads/main'
    paths:
      - 'projects/xxx/*'
      - 'xxx/*'
  when: never

dummy_job:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - echo "Dummy Job"
  rules:
    - *only_on_no_changes
    - when: always


Thank you! It is very interesting, i never used anchors. But can i parametrize paths?
Because i need to do terraform for 5 projects in monorepo, so i have 5 dirs which i should track for changes
rules:
 - *only_on_changes[paths: yyy]

rules:
 - *only_on_changes[paths: zzz]

it will be super good but im not sure how i can do that

That is not possible as far as I know
